# How to start a service automatically when Arch Linux boots?

Tags: arch-linux

I have done a bit of research trying to figure this out only to find various options that seem very convoluted and complicated just to start one service, which is all I need to do.

Basically, I am trying to start `xbindkeys` whenever the desktop environment starts up (or whenever the user logs in).

What are simple options to do this?

Comment: If you don't need it until the desktop environment starts, there are various DE-specific ways to do it which are independent of Arch. For example, [on Xfce](http://wiki.xfce.org/tips#how_to_customize_starting_xfce).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful about the type of service you're trying to start. You correctly determined that `xbindkeys` should start along with the desktop environment, as it needs access to your X11 display, which "start on boot" services would not have. Many people forget this.

---

In most desktop environments, **create `~/.config/autostart/xbindkeys.desktop`** according to the [XDG Autostart specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=xbindkeys
```

Usually this can be done through `cinnamon-session-properties` or similar.

---

Another method is to put the command in the **`~/.xprofile`** script, which is run by most display managers (GDM, KDM, LXDM, LightDM):

```
xbindkeys &
```

If you are using only `startx`, put the same line in your `~/.xinitrc` instead, before the part which starts your desktop environment. Same applies to display managers that invoke `startx`, such as SLiM.

<sup>Some services, including xbindkeys, "detach" themselves so the `&` is not strictly required. However, it won't hurt, and could possibly make startup *faster* since bash detaches before even starting the process. On the other hand, there are some situations where it would hurt – that is, when it's necessary to know when the service has fully initialized.</sup>

---

System-wide services, on the other hand, should be started as systemd services, by creating an `/etc/systemd/system/<name>.service` unit file. They start early and do not have access to any X11 display (and often start before the display manager does).

Comment: According to [bug 845339](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=845339#c3) Fedora doesn't support anymore `~/.xprofile` and `~/.xinitrc`.

Answer (score 1):

xbindkeys is not a service, which would instead require the use of *systemctl*.

However, *xbindkeys* has, like just about anything in Arch, a very good wiki page, [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys), which, states, among other things:

> Once you're done configuring your keys, edit your ~/.xinitrc and place
>
> ```
>  xbindkeys
> ```
>
> before the line that starts your window manager or DE.

You should really start reading the Wiki, it is truly well-written, so much so that I read it even when I have to add/modify configurations to my other, non-Arch Linux systems.

Comment: I did of course read the Wiki, I must have overlooked that critical component. I would not have otherwise known how to setup xbindkeys to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

On my side, I use Cinnamon as Desktop Environment. So I just added `/usr/bin/xbindkeys` in Cinnamon Settings Panel → Startup applications.
This way, `xbindkeys` is launched when my desktop environment starts.
If you don't use Cinnamon, I'm sure you will be able to apply the same thing into your desktop environment.