# Trying to start process on login, but no .xinitrc file to work with

Tags: linux, xorg, arch-linux, xbindkeys

So I installed and am properly using [xbindkeys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys). The problem is that I must manually start this process each time I start my system. I read more into the wiki and found there is a [method](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys#Usage) one can exploit to auto-start this process - editing `~/.xinitrc`. So, I went into that directory and did not find such a file. I then jumped over to the [xinitrc wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xinitrc#Getting_started) to read more about this file.

Apparently, this file apparently is a script read by the `startx/xinit` program that is ran to start basic working environment - or a desktop environment if installed and explicitely coded in the script. From [this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Running) page it reads that:

> In the absence of ~/.xinitrc, startx/xinit defaults to parsing the global file /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc, which starts a basic environment with the Twm window manager, Xclock and Xterm.

It seems confusing considering that I have `cinnamon` installed as my default desktop environment which is started each time I login - but apparently without the use of `.xinitrc` to dictate that. Unless my display manager is starting cinnamon behind-the-scenes I am not quite sure how this is all working.

**The point:** The reason  I bring all that up is because the second link above ([method](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys#Usage)) requires that I edit a file that does not exist, yet the same file is said to be required by the last link ([this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Running)) since my desktop, non-basic, is started on log-in. What is happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`startx` and `~/.xinitrc` isn't the *only* method of starting an X11 environment. Most desktop environments **come with a "display manager" daemon** which automatically starts Xorg on all available monitors, and shows a graphical login screen.

While *some* display managers do try to run `~/.xinitrc` themselves, **most DMs take the list of available "sessions" from `/usr/share/xsessions/*.desktop`**.

As for the other question – starting programs when the desktop environment starts – there usualy are two methods, [as in my earlier post](https://superuser.com/a/755959/1686):

- According to the XDG Autostart specification, the desktop environment's "session manager" (e.g. `cinnamon-session`) will read the programs from `~/.config/autostart/*.desktop`. You can manage them using **`cinnamon-session-properties`**.
- Some display managers will read the **`~/.xprofile`** script, which works similarly to `~/.xinitrc` but *without* starting a window manager (as that's already done by the session manager).

Comment: You must be one of very few in this niche of stack exchange! I do recall reading your answer to that question - that is where I got the idea to use `.xinitrc`. It was just that after reading into that file I was slightly confused as to how it all was working.