# Writing a service that depends on Xorg

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to write a user level service for `redshift`, and it needs to wait until Xorg is up and running. My current service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Redshift
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/bin/redshift -l 28:-13 -t 5300:3300 -b 0.80:0.91 -m randr
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

However, it seems that it attempts to start before Xorg is up, and I have to manually start the service afterwards. I guess I'm using the wrong `After=` target. Any hints?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I've been researching this and grawity's answer seems out of date. You can now setup user services with systemd that run with as part of the user's session. They can have DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY set (currently in Arch, Debian Stretch+ and Ubuntu).

This makes sense over the previous recommendations of using desktop autostart files, as you get process management just like you would a system level app (restart, etc).

Best docs right now is the Arch wiki; [Systemd/User](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User)

TLDR version;

1. Create desired *.service file in `~/.config/systemd/user/`
2. Run `systemctl --user enable [service]` (exclude .service suffix)
3. Optionally run `systemctl --user start [service]` to start now
4. Use `systemctl --user status [service]` to check how it's doing

A couple other useful commands.

- `systemctl --user list-unit-files` - view all user units
- `systemctl --user daemon-reload` - if you edit a .service file

-- Later...

I upgraded and converted most of my session daemons to systemd .service files. So I can add a couple of additional notes.

There was no default hook to run the services at login, so you must trigger it yourself. I do it from my `~/.xsession` file.

```
systemctl --user import-environment PATH DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
systemctl --no-block --user start xsession.target
```

The first line imports some environment variables into the systemd user session and the second kicks off the target. My `xsession.target` file;

```
[Unit]
Description=Xsession running
BindsTo=graphical-session.target
```

My `xbindkeys.service` as an example.

```
[Unit]
Description=xbindkeys
PartOf=graphical-session.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xbindkeys -n -f ${HOME}/projects/dotfiles/.xbindkeysrc
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=xsession.target
```

Comment: @mkaito At https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v219/NEWS#L194 it says "An X11 session scriptlet is now shipped that uploads $DISPLAY and $XAUTHORITY into the environment of the systemd --user daemon if a session begins. This should improve compatibility with X11 enabled applications run as systemd user services."

Comment: Adding `--user` to all commands was a little cumbersome, so I used `alias sessionctl='systemctl --user'` to create an alias.

Answer (score 12):

**The usual hint is "don't".** `redshift` is not a system-wide service – it would have a separate instance for *each session*, and it needs to know about how to connect to that specific session's Xorg.

(Xorg isn't a system service either – only the *display manager* is, and it also launches a separate Xorg for each session. // `graphical.target` will tell you when the display manager is ready, but it says nothing about when the DM actually starts the first – or all – displays.)

Just starting it on boot with `DISPLAY=:0` is not enough, for there is no guarantee that there's exactly one display at any given time, nor that it is always `:0` (for example, if Xorg crashes leaving a stale lockfile, the next one would run at `:1` as it would think `:0` is still occupied); you also need to set the path to your `XAUTHORITY` file as X11 requires authentication; and make sure `redshift` gets restarted if you ever log out & log in again.

**So how to start it?** Almost always, the desktop environment has several methods of starting its own *session* services. [See an older post](https://superuser.com/a/755959/1686) which already describes the two usual ones; the `~/.xprofile` script and the `~/.config/autostart/*.desktop` location.

If you use *startx*, you can use `~/.xinitrc` to start such things. Standalone window managers often have their own startup/init scripts; e.g. `~/.config/openbox/autostart` for Openbox.

What's common to all these methods is that the program is started from *within* the session – avoiding all the problems listed above.

Comment: While redshift is not a system-wide service in many cases it makes sense to be a user service which is exactly what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I just created as workaround to the not yet available `graphical-session.target` (On my Kubuntu 16.04 system):

1. Create a **pseudo systemd user unit** which brings the graphical-session.target up and down.

Create `~/.config/systemd/user/xsession.target` with following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description = Xsession up and running
BindsTo=graphical-session.target
```

Tell systemd about this new unit:

```
$> systemctl --user daemon-reload
```

2. Create **autostart and shutdown scripts** which controls the `xsession.target` via the currently available mechanics of the Ubuntu 16.04 desktop.

Create `~/.config/autostart-scripts/xsession.target-login.sh` with following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! systemctl --user is-active xsession.target &> /dev/null
then
  /bin/systemctl --user import-environment DISPLAY XAUTHORITY
  /bin/systemctl --user start xsession.target
fi
```

Create `~/.config/plasma-workspace/shutdown/xsession.target-logout.sh` with following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

if systemctl --user is-active xsession.target &> /dev/null
then
  /bin/systemctl --user stop xsession.target
fi
```

Make the scripts executable:

```
$> chmod +x ~/.config/autostart-scripts/xsession.target-login.sh
$> chmod +x ~/.config/plasma-workspace/shutdown/xsession.target-logout.sh
```

**Note:** these two files are placed where KDE will pick them up for autostart and shutdown. The files maybe placed somewhere else for other desktop environments (e.g. Gnome) - but I don't know about those environments.

**Note:** This workaround lacks support of multi desktop sessions. It only handles the `graphical-session.target` correctly as long as only one active X11 session is run on a machine (but that's the case for most of us linux users).

3. Create **your own systemd user units** which depend on `graphical-session.target` and have them run cleanly while being logged in on your desktop.

As example @mkaito's unit should look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Redshift
PartOf=graphical-session.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/redshift -l 28:-13 -t 5300:3300 -b 0.80:0.91 -m randr
Restart=always
```

(Don't forget to do a `daemon-reload` after editing your units!)

4. Reboot your machine, login and verfiy your units are started as expected

```
$> systemctl --user status graphical-session.target
● graphical-session.target - Current graphical user session
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/graphical-session.target; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active since Don 2017-01-05 15:08:42 CET; 47min ago
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
$> systemctl --user status your-unit...
```

At some future day (will it be Ubuntu 17.04?) my workaround become obsolete since the system will handle the `graphical-session.target` correctly itself.
At that day just remove the autostart and shutdown script and also the `xsession.target` - your custom user units may stay untouched and just work.

Comment: I know this is an old comment but you can also add startup/login scripts via the System settings app under Workspace > Startup and Shutdown > Autostart, if you want to put those scripts in a place you will remember them.

Answer (score 6):

This solution does exactly what the author of the question asks:

> it needs to wait until Xorg is up and running

While there could be better ways of doing it, as already answered by other users, this is another approach to this problem.

It is similar to systemd's [systemd-networkd-wait-online.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.html) which blocks until certain criteria are met. Other services which depend on it will be launched as soon as this service starts successfully or times out.

Per the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xserver) (section "Files"), X server will create a UNIX socket `/tmp/.X11-unix/Xn` (where `n` is a display number).

By monitoring presence of this socket we can determine that the server for particular display has started.

`confirm_x_started.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]
do
  # Check whether or not socket exists
  if [ -S /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 ]
  then
    exit 0
  fi

  # Adjust timeout according to your needs
  if [ $SECONDS -gt 15 ]
  then
    exit 1
  fi

  sleep 0.5
done
```

---

`x_server_started.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Monitor X server start

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/confirm_x_started.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=example.target
```

---

Now, enable `x_server_started.service` to start at the same time with the X server.

Make other services (which need X server to be started) to depend on `x_server_started.service`

dependent unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service that needs to have the X server started
Requires=x_server_started.service
After=x_server_started.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/binary

[Install]
WantedBy=example.target
```

If X server starts without a problem, the `x_server_started.service` will start almost immediately and systemd will proceed to start all units that are dependent on `x_server_started.service`.

Comment: This works nicely. The extra service is a nice touch. You can also just use ExecStartPre in your target service. I had to add an extra 'sleep 1' before 'exit 0' though, it seems it was a bit too fast to just try and catch X right away.

Comment: could someone please expand on how to "enable x_server_started.service to start at the same time with the X server"?

Comment: @MPA95, Two services will be scheduled to start "at the same time" when they are part of the same [target](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html). In my example, the target is `example.target` as specified in the `[Install]` section. I think X server is part of the `graphical.target`. Enabling the service is done with `systemctl enable x_server_started.service` command. Search on-line for "systemd service management", also read `man systemd.service`

Answer (score 2):

A lot of answers imply that some workarounds or scripts are necessary. At least on a recent GNOME session I do no longer need such workarounds.

If I add `WantedBy=graphical-session.target` then the necessary X11 environment variables (i.e., `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY`) are available to the service and I can execute an X11 program in my user service file:

```
[Unit]
...
PartOf=graphical-session.target

[Service]
...

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target
```

As I understand it, the `graphical-session.target` is a passive target. Using it implies that the actual session which is being started bind to this target via `BindsTo=graphical-session.target`. For the `gnome-session.target` this seems to be the case but it might not be the case for the older or less popular desktop environments.

I found it helpful to inspect the user journal `journalctl --user -b` which prints which targets are reached in which order:

> May 08 21:28:10 earth systemd[2481]: Reached target GNOME printer notifications target.
> May 08 21:28:10 earth systemd[2481]: Reached target GNOME Session.
> May 08 21:28:10 earth systemd[2481]: Reached target GNOME X11 Session (session: gnome-flashback-metacity).
> May 08 21:28:10 earth systemd[2481]: Reached target Current graphical user session.

The log outputs the target's description and we can use the following command to identify the actual target names:

```
systemctl --user list-units --type target
```

See also: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#Special%20Passive%20User%20Units

Comment: display still not available with this graphical-session.targer

Answer (score 0):

On "/usr/lib/systemd/**user**" place a **service** that includes:

```
[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/<user>/.Xauthority
```

If that alone doesn't work, make a **script** that waits the window manager to be up:

```
waitSuccess () {
    local command="${*}"
    
    while ! ${command} &> /dev/null; do
        sleep 0.5
    done
}

waitSuccess "xprop -root -notype _NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK | grep --silent true"
```