# Fedora 20 Systemd slideshow on startup

Tags: gnome, systemd, fedora-20

How do I use systemd  to automatically run a slideshow automatically at startup? I am using Gnome on Fedora 20. eog works well, but I cannot get it to successfully run at startup.

Answer (score 0):

You *do not* use systemd for this. See my [earlier answer](https://superuser.com/a/759891/1686) on why. `eog` is not a system service; it is a desktop program that runs inside the login session, and the correct method to start it is by creating a `*.desktop` file in the `~/.config/autostart` directory:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Slide show
Type=Application
Exec=eog --slide-show ~/Pictures
```